# Can't find a public symbol variable on one instance of a class (Java)

Tags: java, variables, arraylist, scope

I am writing a program to calculate the shortest path between two nodes. In my program I have one custom class called NodeList, which contains an ArrayList of strings (representing nodes) along with a distance. I am using Dijkstra's algorithm which involves opening up the shortest edge from each node. So, I use this loop to tabulate the possible routes from a given point:

```
for ( NodeList ed : edges )
    {
     if (ed.nodeList.get(0).equals(node1))
     {
      routes.add(ed);
     }
    }
```

This works fine, and appears to load the correct values into the variables (according to the debugger). However, when I try and set a variable to the distance of one of the nodes, I get a message "cannot find symbol variable distance". Here is the code that causes the problem:

```
int minDistance = routes.get(0).distance;
```

Is this abnormal or is there something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get(0)` apparently returned an object of class type which doesn't have the particular field.

There are several solutions depending on the root cause of the problem:

- Parameterize the list if possible (e.g. `NodeList<Route>` instead of `NodeList`)
- Cast it to the right type (e.g. `int distance = ((Route) routes.get(0)).distance)`
- Make the field public (e.g. `public int distance;`)
- Add a getter (e.g. `public int getDistance() { return this.distance; }`) and use it.

Answer (score 1):

If the node list doesn't use generics, then the compiler can't tell which type you are `get()`ing, which means it assumes it's an `Object`, which means it has no `distance` member.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense. You say that you have an `ArrayList` of `Strings`, but you are looking for a member called 'distance'. String doesn't have a public field called 'distance'.

Most likely you need to declare `ArrayList<SomeClassOfYours>` to fix this, but I can't tell what from what you posted.

Comment: He said the list has strings and distances, sounds like he means he already is using a class.